# Set width of children as width of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have following structure:

```
<div id="1">
<div class="clone"></div>
</div>

<div id="2">
<div class="clone"></div>
</div>
```

And i want to say to every .clone that the shoud use the width of parent id. Use auto or 100% isn't an option, because the clone is position: fixed.

I have a working code:

```
    $('.clone').width($('.clone').parent().width());
```

but it could be, that the #1 and #2 are different and my thing wouldn't work then. 
so i tried

```
    $('.clone').width($(this).parent().width());
```

but here have somethind to be wrong. Any help?

Comment: Use [the overload of `width()` that takes a function](https://api.jquery.com/width/#width-function).

Comment: A `div` will fill the width of its parent by default, so unless you've got some other CSS interfering this should be working without any additional CSS

Answer (score 1):

Don't think so far!

Just use:

```
.clone {
 width:inherit
}
```